# My Code of C++ is not Working

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I'm a Student of C++ Programming i'm trying to create a age calculater in c++ but i'm Stuck at at multiplying a Variable with a Another Variable 
Here's the Code:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int birthmonth,birthyear,birthdate;
    int currentmonth,currentyear,currentdate;
    int year,month,weeks,cal,calx,days,hours;
    cout<<"Hassan's Age Calculator\n\n";
    cout<<"Enter Your Birth Year(i.e:1996):";
        cin>>birthyear;
    cout<<"\nEnter Your Birth Month(i.e:10):";
        cin>>birthmonth;
    cout<<"\nEnter date of Birth(i.e:27):";
        cin>>birthdate;
    cout<<"\nEnter The Current Month(i.e:7):";
        cin>>currentmonth;
    cout<<"\nEnter The Current Year(i.e:2013):";
        cin>>currentyear;
    cout<<"\nEnter Current Date(i.e:24):";
        cin>>currentdate;
    year=currentyear-birthyear;
    month=year*12;
    weeks=month*4.34;
    cal=(year*365.242)+currentdate;
    calx=cal+30.43;
    days=calx-birthdate;
    hours=days*24;

    cout<<"\n\n\t\tYour Age is "<<year<< " in Years" ;
    cout<<"\n\n\t\tYour Age is "<<month<< " in Months" ;
    cout<<"\n\n\t\tYour Age is "<<weeks<<" in weeks";           
    cout<<"\n\n\t\tYour Age is "<<days<<" in days";
    cout<<"\n\n\t\tYour Age is "<<hours<<" in hours";
    getch();
}
```

see the variable name hours its not working it shows 18640 but it should be 149712 by multiplying the answer of variable (days) to 24, and answer of days is 6238 on the console screen i'm using turbo C 4.0++ and i need help what i m doing wrong.

Comment: "what i m doing wrong" - for one thing, you're using a decades-old compiler that accepts invalid code like `void main()`.

Comment: [Wow, November 1993](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C++#Historical_versions). *Literally* 2 decades old! How did you even get that to run?

Comment: Drop that class and file a complaint against your professor if he is the one who told you to use Turbo C++. Also, you are using floating point arithmetics on integers. You should use `float` or `double` instead of `int`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this calendar.  It's certainly not Gregorian.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like your prehistoric compiler has 16-bit `int` types. 149712 is too large to fit in 16 bits, so the calculation overflows and gives an incorrect value. You should:

- use `long` or `int32_t` if you need a type that's guaranteed to be large enough to represent numbers up to a couple of billion; or perhaps `float` or `double` since you're doing floating-point arithmetic;
- use a modern compiler. There have been two major updates to the language and standard library over the lifetime of that compiler, and the language you are writing is barely recognisable as C++.

Comment: Note that OP is using floating point arithmetic. long and int32_t would lose precision (assuming his formula is correct).

Comment: And to OP : Note that there are many *free* compilers that are very up-to-date and good quality. Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express is entirely free for educational purposes and it also includes an entire IDE.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur Mike's answer sounds more sound. FP arithmetic with automatically casted results, might be an additional flaw in the OPs code.

Comment: @g-makulik I'm not sure I get your comment. The point of suggesting floating-point types is exactly to patch the automatic dropping of decimals :\